# emacs evil-mode: turn off line numbers on particular modes

Tags: ess, evil-mode

I am using emacs+evil+ESS. I have the following in my `.emacs` in order to turn on line numbers in all modes except iESS mode. However, the line numbers in iESS is not turned off. I sometimes have hundred thousand lines in iESS buffer, and it is not nice to have line numbers. How do I turn them off?

```
(line-number-mode 1)            ; have line numbers and
(column-number-mode 1)          ; column numbers in the mode line
(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook (lambda () (line-number-mode 0)))
(global-linum-mode 1)           ; add line numbers on the
```

Answer (score 0):

`line-number-mode` is the wrong mode. It's `linum-mode` that creates the line number column. You'll need to turn that off instead:

`(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))`